# Proof of continuity from above: why doesn't it use $A_{n}\setminus A_{n+1}$ but instead use $A_{1}\setminus A_{n}$.

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I am reviewing some measure theory and when it comes to the continuity from above, my own proof confuses me.

So, continuity from above is like this:

> Let $A_{1}\supseteq A_{2}\supseteq\dots$ be a decreasing sequence of sets and set $A:=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}$. If $\mu(A_{1})<\infty$, then $\mu(A)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_{k}).$

In the proof of continuity from below ($A_{1}\subseteq A_{2}\subseteq\dots\subseteq A:=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}$), it uses the strategy of $$A=A_{1}\cup \bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty}A_{n}\setminus A_{n-1}.$$ Then, one can write $$\mu(A)=\mu(A_{1})-\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=2}^{N}\mu(A_{k})-\mu(A_{k-1})=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_{N}).$$

---

I wonder why the same strategy can't be used: in the case of $A_{1}\supseteq A_{2}\supseteq\dots$, we can express $A:=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}$ as $$A=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}=A_{1}\setminus (A_{1}\setminus A_{2}\cup A_{2}\setminus A_{3}\cup\dots)=A_{1}\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}\setminus A_{k+1}.$$

This will give us the alternating sum again: $$\mu(A)=\mu(A_{1})-\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\mu(A_{k})-\mu(A_{k+1})=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_{N+1}).$$

There must be something wrong here because I did not use the fact that $\mu(A_{1})<\infty$.

---

Edit 1: As suggested by Anne, for the continuity from below, I should assume $\mu(A_{k})<\infty$ for all $k$. If $\mu(A_{k})=\infty$ for some $k$, then by monotonicity $\mu(A)=\infty$, and we still have the desired equality $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_{k})=\infty=\mu(A).$$

Comment: @AnneBauval why?

Comment: Your proof of the continuity from below is already weird. $μ(A_k)−μ(A_{k−1})$
 makes no sense if $μ(A_k)=μ(A_{k−1})=\infty.$ For a correct proof of that first part, see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2912794/386889).

Comment: @AnneBauval in this case, since $A_{k}\subseteq A$, $\mu(A)=\infty$, and $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_{k})=\infty$, so we still have $\mu(A)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_{k})$ without the need to go through the alternating-sum proof.

Comment: Ok then (but this part was missing). But what about $\infty-\infty$ in your proof from above?

Comment: @AnneBauval yeah my bad. Let me edit the post. 

so, for the continuity from above, the problem you mentioned still exists, but I can use $\mu(A_{1})<\infty$ to make sure $\mu(A_{k})<\infty$ for all $k$, and the proof goes through?

the difference is that if $\mu(A_{1})=\infty$, then this proof can't work because we don't know about $\mu(A_{k})$, and we cannot use monotonicity to argue that $\mu(A)=\infty$ because $A_{1}\supseteq A$?

Comment: I agree with everything + may be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771635) helps.

Comment: @AnneBauval Great! Ty for help and reference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will summarize the comment.

For continuity from below, one can use $\{E_{n}\}$ defined by $E_{1}:=A_{1}$ and $E_{n}:=A_{n}\setminus A_{n-1}$. Then, observe that $A_{k}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{k}E_{n}$. But instead of using the alternating sum, we can directly have $$\mu(A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mu(E_{k})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu\Big(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}E_{k}\Big)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_{n}).$$ In this way, we don't need to argue for the case where $\mu(A_{k})=\infty$ for some $k$.

For continuity from above, note that we don't need to require $\mu(A_{1})<\infty$. What we need to require in general is actually $\mu(A_{N})<\infty$ for some $N$.

Then, one can instead define $E_{n}:=A_{N}\setminus A_{N+n}$. And we observe that $$\bigcap_{k=N}^{\infty}A_{k}=A_{N}\setminus(A_{N}\setminus\bigcup_{k=N+1}^{\infty}A_{k})=A_{N}\setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}.$$ To observe this, simply use the idea that $\bigcap_{k=N}^{\infty}A_{k}=\Big(\bigcup_{k=N}^{\infty}A_{k}^{c}\Big)^{c}$ but now the ambient space is $A_{N}$. Note that $E_{1}\subseteq E_{2}\subseteq\dots\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}$, so the continuity from below implies that $$\mu\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}\Big)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(E_{n})=\mu(A_{N})-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_{N+n}).$$ And thus $$\mu(A)=\mu(A_{N})-\mu\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}\Big)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_{N+n}),$$ where $\mu(A_{N})$ canceled because it is finite.

However, I do believe that my proof is more instructive in the reason why $\mu(A_{N})<\infty$ is required for the continuity from above. It is not good to simply say that "oh we require this because the proof uses it". How do you know if there is another proof not using it? And, what is the difference between the proof of continuity from below and above? As what we proved, the case where $\mu(A_{k})=\infty$ should always be considered --- it was only bypassed by the proof without using the alternating sum. For continuity from below, even though $\mu(A_{k})=\infty$, we can still have required identity because $A_{k}\subseteq A$. However, in the proof of continuity from above, if $\mu(A_{N})=\infty$, then $\mu(A_{k})=\infty$ for all $k\leq N$, but since $A_{N}\supseteq A_{N+1}\supseteq\dots\supseteq A$, we don't really know if $\mu(A_{k})=\infty$ or $<\infty$ for $k>N$. In particular, if $\mu(A)<\infty$, then the desired equality will not be true. See below for a  counterexample.

Set $\mathbb{N}:=\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$. Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{N}, 2^{\mathbb{N}},\mu)$ where $\mu$ is the counting measure defined by
$$\mu(A):=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
 \#(A),\ \text{if}\ A\ \text{is finite}\\ 
 \infty,\ \text{if}\ A\ \text{is countably infinite}.
 \end{array}
\right.$$
Consider $A_{n}:=\{k\in\mathbb{N}:k\geq n\}.$ Then, we have $A_{1}\supseteq A_{2}\supseteq\dots$. Moreover, each $A_{n}$ is countably infinite, and thus $\mu(A_{n})=\infty$ for all $n$, which implies that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_{n})=\infty$. However, $A:=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}=\varnothing.$ To see this, if $a\in A$, then $a\in A_{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which means that $a\in\mathbb{N}$ is such that $a\geq n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which is absurd because $a<a+1$ and $a+1\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $\mu(A)=0$. The desired equality of continuity from above does not hold.